# Cumulative Return For the following data

Tags: algorithm, trading, algorithmic-trading, quantitative-finance, quantitative

Actually I was reading a blog on how to calculate the `cumulating return` of a stock for each day.
The formula that was described in the blog to calculate `cumulating return` was
 `(1 + TodayReturn) * (1 + Cumulative_Return_Of_Previous_Day) - 1` , but still I am not able to calculate the cumulative return that was provided on it.

Can someone please make this clear that how is `cumulative return` has been calculated in the table given below. This would be a lot of help.

Thanks in advance.

```
| Days  | Stock Price | Return | Cumulative Return|
---------------------------------------------------
| Day 1 | 150         |        |                  |
| Day 2 | 153         | 2.00 % | 2.00 %           |
| Day 3 | 160         | 4.58 % | 6.67 %           |
| Day 4 | 163         | 1.88 % | 8.67 %           |
| Day 5 | 165         | 1.23 % | 10.00 %          |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Take day 5 for example. The `Return` is calculated as `165/163 = 1.01227`. Subtract 1 to get the increase in price, multiply by 100 to convert to a percentage, and round to 2 digits after the decimal point to get 1.23 %. The `Cumulative Return` is calculated as `165 / 150 = 1.1` which converts to 10.00 %. So the difference is that `Return` uses the previous day's price, and `Cumulative Return` uses the Day 1 price.

Comment: The formula in the blog is a bad idea, because it will accumulate rounding errors.